# Value showing undefined when trying to output data returned as json from server

Tags: javascript, php, json, mongodb, yii2

I am new to Yii2 framework and PHP.I used Mongo DB as the backend database.I fetched a document from a collection and returned the data as Json from the controller.The data returned back is given below.

```
{
    "55b08c383e1a36233fdbdc06": { 
        "_id": { "$id": "55b08c383e1a36233fdbdc06" }, 
        "address": [ "abcdgt", "zxcv" ], 
        "age": "23", 
        "email": [ "qwert@gmail.com","abcd@mail.com" ], 
        "location": "kollam", 
        "name": "ajiths",
        "phoneno": [ "9522585456", "7875642256" ] ,
        "sex": "male" 
     }
}
```

But I am getting 'Undefined' when trying to alert  **result.name** in Javascript code.The code at the front end is given below.

```
function loadClient(id){
         url = "<?=  Yii::getAlias('@serverpathweb')?>/client/showclient?id="+id;
           $.ajax({
          url: url ,
          method: "GET",
           success: function(result){
             alert(result.name);

                 }
             });
    }
```

The code at the controller end is given below.

```
public function actionShowclient($id) {

       $clientdetail = Yii::$app->mongodb->getCollection('client');
       $result = $clientdetail->find(["_id" =>$id]);
       Yii::$app->response->format = \yii\web\Response::FORMAT_JSON;
       return $result;
    }
```

Can anyone tell me how to get the value **result.name**.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

your getting JSON result with id as `key` so access ur `JSON` data like this
first get the key of ur JSON using `Object.keys`
next using key print the values you need

```
var id=Object.keys(result)[0]; //it will print your JSON key i.e. "55b08c383e1a36233fdbdc06"

alert(result[id]['name']); // it will print the name
```

Note if you are getting multiple user details please let me know

Answer (score 0):

Your "result" object is probably a String because you're not telling jQuery otherwise. Trying adding the option dataType:json to your request as in:

```
$.ajax({ url: url, method: 'GET', dataType: 'json', etc...
```

Edit: It also looks like there's a simple bug in your code. You need to access your property where it's nested in the resulting object:

```
result[id].name
```

Comment: sorry still not getting the answer.I have tried $.ajax({
          url: url ,
          method: "GET",
          dataType: 'json',
           success: function(result){
             alert(result.name);
             
                 }
             });

Comment: Actually, if the JSON response you have at the top is what you're getting back as your data then it looks like there's a simple bug in your code. I'll update my answer...